# first order differential equation and summation problem

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, summation

find $a_n$ and f(x) so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$ satisfy $f'(x)-f(x)=x^2$ and  $f(0)=1$

here I tried to find $f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}$ 
from $\frac{df(x)}{dx}-f(x)=x^2$ using first order differential equation  I got $y=x^2+2x+1$ 
  -> f(x)? 
but I don't know what is the relation of the summation and first order differential equation. and how to find $f(x)$ and $a_n$ can someone give me hint? thanks!

Comment: What is $(-1)!$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If we assume a Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ at $x_0=0$ by 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{n!}x^n$$

what can we conclude for $f(x=0)$ from the Taylor series for the constant $a_0$? Write the first terms of the series to see what happens.

The derivative is given as (note the change of the summation index!)

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{n!}x^{n}.$$

Plug this into the differential equation:

$$f'(x)-f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{n!}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{n!}x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{n!}-\dfrac{a_n}{n!}\right]x^{n} = 0\cdot x^0 + 0\cdot x^1 + 1\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3+\ldots.$$

What can you conclude by comparing the coefficients? Use the value of $a_0$.

---

Alternative approach

Use that $a_n=\dfrac{d^{n}f(0)}{dx^n}$ and use the differential equation as a recursion formula

$$f'(0)+f(0)=0^2 \implies f'(0)=-f(0)=-1$$
$$f''(0)+f'(0)=2\cdot 0 \implies f''(0)=-f'(0)=1$$
$$f'''(0)+f''(0)=2 \implies f'''(0)=2-f''(0)$$
$$f^{(4)}(0)=-f'''(0)$$

and so forth.

Comment: oh I got it! just comparing coefficient. so $a_1-a_0= 0$ , $a_2-a_1=0 $  $a_3-a_2=2$ ,, since $a_0=0$ , so $a_1=1$ $a_2=1$ $a_3=3$ so does $a_4 a_5 a_.... = 3$

Comment: thankyou so much for detailed explanation! actually this is the maclaurin expansion of e at x=0(?) for second approach $f''(0)+f'(0)=2\cdot 0^2 \implies f''(0)=-f'(0)=1$, wasn't sure how did you know the coefficient is 2?

Comment: There was a small typo in the power of zero. If you take the differential equation and differentiate it with respect to $x$ you obtain $f''(x)+f'(x)=2x$ evaluate at $x=0$ to obtain $f''(0)+f'(0)=2\cdot 0$.

Comment: thanks!!! I got it!!! Really appreciate for the help, i found another method by integrating the first differential equation and find $C$ using the $f(0)=1$ and then expanding the C which is $e^x$ and got the coefficient $a_n$. Seems there are many ways to approach this problem.